# Saving Activity State -

Tags: android, bundle

In my application, There is an activity UserMenu, in which (at on create) subsequent loading  is done. I want that next time when the application is opened, this screen should not be reloaded again - I want to save the state of the UserMenu screen as it is.

I have been moving through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-activity-state-in-android), but I am unable to look what I have to implement, I dont want to save any values, simply I want to recreate the same screen as I can get on pressing the home button in android.

Kindly help  me regarding my matter.

Thanks

Comment: can you describe subsequent loading in brief?what exactly do you want to save as the state of your screen?

Comment: I have an expandable list view and that gets loaded with its arraylists for the group and child and also in the asynctask some API are calling in the background

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

In your UserMenu Activity class

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            goToHome();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    private void goToHome() {
        moveTaskToBack(true);

    }
```

So when you will press back button the Activity will no be destroyed and move to Home and once you will long press Home Button or start your app from menu it wont load the Activity again.

Thanks

Comment: Amit, Its not a good solution. What Will happen when I clear the application from the task manager ??????

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible according to me as like what you are saying about home button. when home button is pressed your activity goes in `onPause()` and when you reopen it comes in `onResume()`. You can do what is suggested in the link you are following i.e you can save the values of your `Actvity` elements using `onSavedInstanceState()` also it is no guaranteed to execute read this [onSavedInstanceState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29)

Answer (score 0):

you need to follow the [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html) to make it simple.just make a function call from `onCreate()` method to load those data,save the data in some standalone class using `ArrayList()`,and in `onResume()` display the stored data from `ArrayList()`.and yes,inside `onCreate()` check for the size of that `ArrayList()` just to decide whether the data has already been loaded or not.if it has not been loaded,load it.otherwise don't load.